# Why does OpenCover not find all the modules when running code through NUnit?

Tags: .net, nunit, opencover

I have a script that runs NUnit through OpenCover. The script can be given a list of assembly names to limit the coverage.
Unfortunately, OpenCover does not see all the modules.

I run my script with 3 parameters:

1. The unit test dll path - `.\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll`
2. The list of assembly names - `DataSvc,DataProcessor,xyz.DataManager`
3. The filter for nunit - `class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest`

Like this:

```
C:\xyz\tip> Start-TestsWithCoverage .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll -AssemblyNames DataSvc,DataProcessor,xyz.DataManager -Where "class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest"
```

The script outputs the OpenCover filter built from the given assembly names:

```
Using filter +[DataSvc]* +[DataProcessor]* +[xyz.DataManager]*
```

Then it proceeds to output the OpenCover command line. I used `~` to replace my user profile path for brevity.

```
& ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\OpenCover.4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -output:~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml `
            -log:Info `
            -mergeoutput `
            -register:user `
            -filter:+[DataSvc]* +[DataProcessor]* +[xyz.DataManager]* `
            -target:~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe `
            -hideskipped:MissingPdb `
            -skipautoprops `
            -mergebyhash `
            -targetargs:"--workers=1 --trace=Info --stoponerror --result=~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.TestResult.xml --noh --noc --inprocess --domain=Single --where:`"class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest`" .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" `
        | & Write-Host
```

Now the command executes and produces the following output:

```
Executing: ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll

Test Filters
    Where: class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest


Run Settings
    ProcessModel: InProcess
    DomainUsage: Single
    DisposeRunners: True
    InternalTraceLevel: Info
    WorkDirectory: C:\xyz\tip
    StopOnError: True
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 1
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 501, Passed: 501, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-06-11 17:53:29Z
    End time: 2019-06-11 17:56:10Z
    Duration: 161.509 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
    1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
    output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
    2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
    guide and the -register switch.

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CoverageResult                 ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml
TestResult                     ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
```

Examining the modules reported in the OpenCoverResult.xml yields this:

```
C:\xyz\tip> cat ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml | sls "ModulePath>C:\\xyz"

      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\SchedulePolicyValidation.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\xyz.Data.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\xyz.WFM.Core.WorkContractPremium.Engine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\MultiApprovalProcessor.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\HRMappingRuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\xyz.Common.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\AccrualEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngineHelper.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\StaffAssignment.dll</ModulePath>
```

Notice none of the assembly names I asked for. Maybe they do not have PDBs? But they do:

```
C:\xyz\tip> 'DataSvc','DataProcessor', 'xyz.DataManager' |% { dir ".\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\$_.*" }


    Directory: C:\xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        6/11/2019  12:44 PM       15237632 DataSvc.dll
-a----        6/11/2019  12:44 PM       18771456 DataSvc.pdb
-a----        6/11/2019  12:34 PM        1762816 DataProcessor.dll
-a----        6/11/2019  12:34 PM        2334208 DataProcessor.pdb
-a----        6/11/2019  12:34 PM         181760 xyz.DataManager.dll
-a----        6/11/2019  12:34 PM         368128 xyz.DataManager.pdb
```

Or maybe the assembly names are different from the file names? Nope:

```
C:\xyz\tip> 'DataSvc','DataProcessor', 'xyz.DataManager' |% { [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName("$pwd\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\$_.dll") }

Version        Name
-------        ----
1.0.0.0        DataSvc
1.0.0.0        DataProcessor
1.0.0.0        xyz.DataManager
```

Or maybe the exercised tests just do not load these assemblies into memory? Nope again. I do not know how to test it, except by deleting them and rerunning the script:

```
C:\xyz\tip> 'DataSvc','DataProcessor', 'xyz.DataManager' |% { del ".\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\$_.*" }
C:\xyz\tip> 'DataSvc','DataProcessor', 'xyz.DataManager' |% { dir ".\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\$_.*" }
C:\xyz\tip>  Start-TestsWithCoverage .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll -AssemblyNames DataSvc,DataProcessor,xyz.DataManager -Where "class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest"
Using filter +[DataSvc]* +[DataProcessor]* +[xyz.DataManager]*
& ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\OpenCover.4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -output:~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611141815\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml `
            -log:Info `
            -mergeoutput `
            -register:user `
            -filter:+[DataSvc]* +[DataProcessor]* +[xyz.DataManager]* `
            -target:~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe `
            -hideskipped:MissingPdb `
            -skipautoprops `
            -mergebyhash `
            -targetargs:"--workers=1 --trace=Info --stoponerror --result=~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611141815\UnitTests.TestResult.xml --noh --noc --inprocess --domain=Single --where:`"class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest`" .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" `
        | & Write-Host
Executing: ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll

Test Filters
    Where: class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest


Errors, Failures and Warnings

1) Invalid : UnitTests.dll
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'xyz.DataManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'xyz.DataManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'xyz.DataManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'xyz.DataManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Execution terminated after first error

Run Settings
    ProcessModel: InProcess
    DomainUsage: Single
    DisposeRunners: True
    InternalTraceLevel: Info
    WorkDirectory: C:\xyz\tip
    StopOnError: True
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 1
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-06-11 18:18:17Z
    End time: 2019-06-11 18:18:17Z
    Duration: 0.810 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611141815\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
    1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
    output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
    2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
    guide and the -register switch.

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CoverageResult                 ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611141815\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml
TestResult                     ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611141815\UnitTests.TestResult.xml


C:\xyz\tip>
```

So, the answer is nope - the assemblies are loaded. So, what do I have:

1. There are actual assemblies matching the given assembly names
2. They have PDBs
3. They are loaded by the unit tests
4. Yet OpenCover does not report them

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

I have just run without any filter:

```
C:\Xyz\tip> Start-TestsWithCoverage .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll -Where "class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest"
& ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\OpenCover.4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -output:~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611200801\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml `
            -log:Info `
            -mergeoutput `
            -register:user `
             `
            -target:~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe `
            -hideskipped:MissingPdb `
            -skipautoprops `
            -mergebyhash `
            -targetargs:"--workers=1 --trace=Info --stoponerror --result=~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611200801\UnitTests.TestResult.xml --noh --noc --inprocess --domain=Single --where:`"class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest`" .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" `
        | & Write-Host
Executing: ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll

Test Filters
    Where: class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest


Run Settings
    ProcessModel: InProcess
    DomainUsage: Single
    DisposeRunners: True
    InternalTraceLevel: Info
    WorkDirectory: C:\Xyz\tip
    StopOnError: True
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 1
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 501, Passed: 501, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-06-12 00:08:02Z
    End time: 2019-06-12 00:12:59Z
    Duration: 296.238 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611200801\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
Committing...
Source file is modified: C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\DeviceServices\DeviceServicesTest.cs
Visited Classes 20 of 5617 (0.36)
Visited Methods 46 of 34372 (0.13)
Visited Points 133 of 335922 (0.04)
Visited Branches 67 of 169563 (0.04)

==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
Alternative Visited Classes 20 of 10833 (0.18)
Alternative Visited Methods 46 of 44579 (0.1)

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CoverageResult                 ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611200801\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml
TestResult                     ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611200801\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
```

The produced file is quite big:

```
C:\Xyz\tip> dir ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611192946\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml


    Directory: ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611192946


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        6/11/2019   7:33 PM      170794313 UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml


C:\Xyz\tip>
```

But it still does not contain the assemblies I am absolutely sure are loaded:

```
C:\Xyz\tip> cat ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190611192946\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml | sls "ModulePath>C:\\Xyz"

      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\SchedulePolicyValidation.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.Data.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.WFM.Core.WorkContractPremium.Engine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\MultiApprovalProcessor.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\HRMappingRuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>


C:\Xyz\tip>
```

Neither DataSvc, not DataProcessor nor Xyz.DataManager are there.

**EDIT 2**

I was asked to run the OpenCover executable directly, so here we go:

```
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> $d = Get-DumpDir
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> $d
~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190612091253
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> dir $d
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> $OpenCover = (Resolve-Path '~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\OpenCover.4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe').Path
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> $NUnit = (Resolve-Path '~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe').Path
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> $CovResult = "$d\UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml"
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> $NUnitResult = "$d\UnitTests.TestResult.xml"
C:\Xyz\tip [master ↓290 +9 ~1 -0 !]> & $OpenCover -output:$CovResult -log:Info -mergeoutput -register:user -target:$NUnit -hideskipped:MissingPdb -skipautoprops -mergebyhash `
>> -targetargs:"--workers=1 --trace=Info --stoponerror --result=$NUnitResult --noh --inprocess --domain=Single --where:`"class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest`" .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll"
Executing: ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll

Test Filters
    Where: class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest


Run Settings
    ProcessModel: InProcess
    DomainUsage: Single
    DisposeRunners: True
    InternalTraceLevel: Info
    WorkDirectory: C:\Xyz\tip
    StopOnError: True
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 1
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 501, Passed: 501, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-06-12 13:15:34Z
    End time: 2019-06-12 13:20:17Z
    Duration: 283.230 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190612091253\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
Committing...
Source file is modified: C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\DeviceServices\DeviceServicesTest.cs
Visited Classes 20 of 5617 (0.36)
Visited Methods 46 of 34372 (0.13)
Visited Points 133 of 335922 (0.04)
Visited Branches 67 of 169563 (0.04)

==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
Alternative Visited Classes 20 of 10833 (0.18)
Alternative Visited Methods 46 of 44579 (0.1)
C:\Xyz\tip>
```

The reported modules are:

```
C:\Xyz\tip> cat $CovResult | sls "ModulePath>C:\\Xyz"

      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\SchedulePolicyValidation.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.Data.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.WFM.Core.WorkContractPremium.Engine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\MultiApprovalProcessor.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\HRMappingRuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.Common.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\AccrualEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngineHelper.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\StaffAssignment.dll</ModulePath>
```

Needless to say, this list is very short. Too short. None of the missing assemblies are .NET Core. 
I am more than willing to provide more information, just let me know what exactly.

**EDIT 3**

Same command line only without `-merge...` and `-hideskipped...` flags:

```
C:\Xyz\tip> $d = Get-DumpDir
C:\Xyz\tip> dir $d
C:\Xyz\tip> $d
~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190614085640
C:\Xyz\tip> & $OpenCover -output:$CovResult -log:Info -register:user -target:$NUnit -targetargs:"--workers=1 --trace=Info --stoponerror --result=$NUnitResult --noh --inprocess --domain=Single --where:`"class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest`" .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll"
Executing: ~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    .\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll

Test Filters
    Where: class==DeviceServicesTest.PunchProcessingTest


Run Settings
    ProcessModel: InProcess
    DomainUsage: Single
    DisposeRunners: True
    InternalTraceLevel: Info
    WorkDirectory: C:\Xyz\tip
    StopOnError: True
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 1
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 500, Passed: 500, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-06-14 12:57:10Z
    End time: 2019-06-14 13:01:54Z
    Duration: 283.427 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190614084338\UnitTests.TestResult.xml
Committing...
Visited Classes 20 of 10321 (0.19)
Visited Methods 56 of 154629 (0.04)
Visited Points 143 of 456738 (0.03)
Visited Branches 77 of 289454 (0.03)

==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
Alternative Visited Classes 20 of 10857 (0.18)
Alternative Visited Methods 56 of 164855 (0.03)
C:\Xyz\tip> dir $CovResult


    Directory: ~\AppData\Local\Temp\a24272_20190614084338


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        6/14/2019   9:02 AM      262507890 UnitTests.CoverageResult.xml


C:\Xyz\tip> cat $CovResult | sls "ModulePath>C:\\Xyz"

      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\SchedulePolicyValidation.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.Data.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.WFM.Core.WorkContractPremium.Engine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\MultiApprovalProcessor.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\HRMappingRuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\Xyz.Common.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\AccrualEngine.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\RuleEngineHelper.dll</ModulePath>
      <ModulePath>C:\Xyz\tip\Test\UnitTests\bin\Debug\StaffAssignment.dll</ModulePath>


C:\Xyz\tip>
```

Same result.

Comment: Try without your script (i.e. command line only) and with default filters and work forward. If the assembly is loaded and it is a .net assembly then opencover should load it - it may have issues with .net core assemblies though depending on version

Comment: Can you add what `~\AppData\Local\Temp\a35044_20190611135327\UnitTests.TestResult.xml` looks like?

Comment: @ShaunWilde - please, see **EDIT 2**

Comment: @Chris - are you looking for anything in particular? I can post it in the paste bin, if you wish or grep for whatever you think is useful and include in the question.

Comment: @mark - Never mind, I think the bit I was hoping to see is already in your question. Sorry - I guess your problem may lie with opencover rather than NUnit, which I'm not familiar with.